# Django - Use annotation in query - Related Field got invalid lookup

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-annotate

In my manager, I've overriden `get_queryset` to annotate `sqft_annotated` value.

```
class RealestateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            sqft_annotated=Coalesce('sqft_a', 'sqft_b', 'sqft_c')
```

I use this value frequently but now, in this query, it raises error (probably because it isn't annotated):

```
_a = Q(realestates__home_type__in=[constants.HOME_TYPES.HOME_TYPE__SINGLE_FAMILY, constants.HOME_TYPES.HOME_TYPE__FARM],
          realestates__sqft_annotated__gte=1100, ...)
_b = Q(<QUERY>)
_c = Q(<QUERY>)

leads_query = Q(Q(_a | _b) | ~_c)


Category.objects.annotate(lead_count=Count('realestates', filter=leads_query)).annotate(
            lead_perc=Case(When(lead_count=0, then=0), default=(Count(
                'realestates', filter=leads_query) / float(total)) * 100))
```

**ERROR**

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: sqft_annotated
```

Can I somehow use the `sqft_annotated` in such query?

PS: Tried to set `base_manager_name` in `class Meta` - didn't help.

Comment: The default manager (in your case `RealestateManager`) is not used for relations. For relations Django use base manager, which is typically `django.db.models.Manager`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#s-using-managers-for-related-object-access

Comment: Same issue here. Would be really great to have an option to allow for querying related objects while making use of the annotations on that related object added through the manager. @Milano have you found any solution?